# Testing a utility method that doesn't belong to a class in django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I have a file I created called `utils.py`

In that I have a few little methods that don't really belong on a model, they don't really belong in the view.

They don't do a lot of work and are just used once or twice in my application so I felt they best fit into a 'utility' kind of role.

My question is - how do I test them?

I currently test my models and forms - but I wanted to put together some tests to go against this utils file, too. I just don't know how to do that without a class to call in the `test_utils.py` file

Comment: What's the problem? Just import those functions and call them.

Comment: For example, in testing models you begin with: `class YourClassTest(TestCase):` ; how would I start the method from the utils file that isn't associated with a class?

Comment: The... exact same way? Note that neither `YourClassTest` nor `TestCase` is a class defined in the code under test, just part of the `unittest` setup.

Comment: It works - just as you said (thank you!), but I just want to make sure I'm grasping it correctly. Essentially, I could use *any* `AnyClassTest` to test the utility methods, right?